# Mule CXF Marshall Response

Tags: cxf, mule

I am using cxf:jaxws-client in Mule 3 and the response I get from my web service call is of type ReleasingInputStream. I have tried adding the http-response-to-message-transformer, but that generates an error - does anyone know how I can retrieve the response as an object as opposed to a ReleasingInputStream?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the issue put the `<cxf-client>` inside the `<outbound-endpoint>` section (NOT BEFORE IT), by modifying the following code

```
    <cxf:jaxws-client
        clientClass="com.xyz.services.WSServices"
            port="WSServicesSoap"
            wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl-file.wsdl"
            operation="GimmeDataOperation" />
    <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8083/OutboundService" />
```

which produces a `ReleasingInputStream` output to

```
    <outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://localhost:8083/OutboundService" >
        <cxf:jaxws-client
            clientClass="com.xyz.services.WSServices"
            port="WSServicesSoap"
            wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl-file.wsdl"
            operation="GimmeDataOperation" />
    </outbound-endpoint>
```

that returns the expected object.

Answer (score 1):

I was just having this same problem.  I solved it by adding an ObjectToString transformer to the response side of the outbound endpoint like this:

```
<mule>
   <object-to-string-transformer name="ObjectToString"/>

   <flow>
      ...
      ...
      ...
      <cxf:jaxws-client clientClass="com.my.ClientClass"
                        port="MyPort" 
                        wsdlLocation="classpath:MyWsdl.wsdl"
                        operation="MyOperation" />
      <outbound-endpoint address="http://some.address/path/to/service"
                         exchange-pattern="request-response" 
                         responseTransformer-refs="ObjectToString" />
      ...
      ...
      ...
   </flow>
</mule>
```

Comment: cheers, does the response come back as a string as a response or the appropriate object? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of jaxws-client is to receive the unmarshaled Java object, so getting the WS response as a String or ReleasingInputStream should not even be an option.

To make the <cxf:jaxws-client> "work" as one would expect the WS client to work - put the INSIDE of the <outbound-endpoint> you will be getting a correct Java object as a payload.